# FInd a sub-class which matches in a List of Options of classes in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list: List[Option[ParentClass]].

```
case class ParentClass

case class ChildClassA

case class ChildClassB
```

What is a good way to find a item in that list which is of type ChildClassB. I have something like this, this is not a good way to do it.

```
def childClassB: Option[ChildClassB] = connections.find( 
        _.get.name == "ChildClassB" ).flatten.asInstanceOf[Option[ChildClassB]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `collectFirst` to find the first element that matches a `PartialFunction`. In this case, the first element that matches a child class:

```
class ParentClass

case class ChildClassA extends ParentClass

case class ChildClassB extends ParentClass

val list: List[Option[ParentClass]] = List(Some(new ChildClassA), None, Some(new ChildClassB), Some(new ChildClassB))

list.flatten.collectFirst{ case b: ChildClassB => b }

res1: Option[ChildClassB] = Some(ChildClassB@7fc1a698)
```

Note that `ParentClass` cannot be a case class for the child classes to extend it.

Comment: How can this do a case b: ChildClassB, shouldn't it be a case b: Option[ChildClassB]?

Comment: @Phil I used `flatten` on the `List` first, which removes all instances of `None`, and extracts the defined values. Without `flatten`, you would match against `Some(b: ChildClassB)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collectFirst`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@collectFirst%5BB%5D%28pf%3aPartialFunction%5BA,B%5D%29%3aOption%5BB%5D), which takes a partial function and returns an `Option` of the first element that matches. In your case, your partial function doesn't need to modify the argument, and because you can only match certain inputs, your output can be the correct type without any casting. Plus, you can use the same pattern matching to ignore `None`s.

```scala
def childClassB(connections: List[Option[ParentClass]]): Option[ChildClassB] = {
  connections.collectFirst { case Some(x: ChildClassB) => x }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
class ParentClass

case class ChildClassA extends ParentClass

case class ChildClassB extends ParentClass
```

one can also use following options to find `ChildClassB`

`find`

```
list.flatten.find {  ele => ele.isInstanceOf[ChildClassB] }.get
```

`dropWhile` //works only when at-least one element of the list is `ChildClassB`

```
list.flatten.dropWhile {  ele => !ele.isInstanceOf[ChildClassB] }.head
```

`takeWhile`  //works only when at-least one element of the list is `ChildClassB`

```
list.flatten.takeWhile  {  ele => ele.isInstanceOf[ChildClassB] }.head
```